# Incorrect text position in HTML email with background image

Tags: html, css, streamreader, mailmessage

**I have a Console app that sends invitations to new users.
I'm trying to send an HTML email that is just an image with custom text written on top of it.**

The HTML file looks like this when you open it on a web browser (the $$Centered$$ is placeholder text that i will replace later, the rest is the background image):

[image]

This is the Html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: #0d2a40;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 90px;
  font-family: "Neue Helvetica W01", Arial, Roboto, sans-serif;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  cursor:pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
      <img src="$$Image$$" usemap="#imgmap" />
  <div class="centered">$$Centered$$</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The image and the HTML file are on a folder called Canvas inside the main project.

This is the code I am using to send the email, I use a StreamReader to take the HTML and replace the placeholder text with my own thing, because it has to be a message with the name of the reader of the email. I also replace the $$Image$$ with the background image's path:

```
            string filepath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filepath + "//Canvas//Canvas.html");
            string readFile = reader.ReadToEnd();
            string myString = "";
            myString = readFile;
            myString = myString.Replace("$$Centered$$", "Hola");
            myString = myString.Replace("$$Image$$", filepath + "//Canvas//Canvas.png");
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            smtp.EnableSsl = false;
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
            smtp.Host = settings.MailServerAddress;
            smtp.Port = settings.MailServerPort;
            message.To.Add("myemail@outlook.com");
            message.From = new MailAddress(settings.FromAddress, settings.FromName);
            message.Subject = settings.SubjectNotificacion;
            message.Body = myString;
            message.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;

            smtp.Send(message);
            reader.Dispose();
```

The email gets sent and the text is indeed replaced with "Hola". The problem is that the background image appears to be rendered before the custom text that goes on top of it, so the received email ends up looking like this:

[image]

**Is there a way to fix this so the text goes where it's supposed to like in the first image?**

Answer (score 0):

In HTML-Emails it is best to put your CSS code inside your HTML tags as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container" style="
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: #0d2a40;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 90px;
  font-family: "Neue Helvetica W01", Arial, Roboto, sans-serif;
  ">
      <img src="$$Image$$" usemap="#imgmap" />
  <div class="centered" style="
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  cursor:pointer;
  ">$$Centered$$</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This has worked for me when I have encountered similar issues.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but sadly this didnt work, the issue still happens.